# EntryPoint Not Found

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I'm trying to use Platform Invoke to executions some functions in a C++ DLL from C#. I'm getting a EntryPoint Not Found error and I'm having trouble figuring out why. Hope someone can help me out. :)

C++ Declaration:

[image: Declaration]

C# PInvoke Code:

[image: PInvoke]

Dumpbin and Error:

[image: Dump]
[image]

**EDIT:** Using `EntryPoint="?CreateClass@Drive@UnmanagedDLL@@QAEPAV12@XZ"` works, but shouldn't I juse be able to reference CreateClass?

Comment: Did you even Google "c++ name mangling pinvoke"

Comment: @ta.speot.is that's why he's using extern "C" anyway problem is he is **trying to export a class method**...I wonder why it even compiles!

Comment: You cannot pinvoke a C++ instance method, you are not passing the required *this* argument.  Nor can you, a C++/CLI wrapper is required.  The Create/DisposeClass() methods should be *static* btw.

Comment: @HansPassant I have been trying for a few days now to get C++/CLI wrappers to work with any luck and that is why I'm trying something different with PInvoke now.

Comment: @Duane C++/CLI has been made for that scenario...PInvoke will always be more _painful_...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I was often experiencing Linker errors when I was trying to use C++/CLI and despite looking at many articles and following them, I couldn't get it working. None of the examples I found would run either, probably due to them being made in VS2005, 10 etc. when I'm using 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code block:

```
extern "C" UNMANAGEDLL_API Drive* Drive::CreateClass()
{
    return new Drive();
}
```

Are you trying to export a class method with C linkage? I wonder why it even compiles. Functions exported with C linkage shouldn't be class methods:

```
Drive* Drive::CreateClass()
{
    return new Drive();
}

extern "C" UNMANAGEDLL_API Drive* CreateClass()
{
    return Drive::CreateClass();
}
```

This is because C linkage cannot be applied to a class method (it needs `thiscall` and name mangling). Can you `DllImport` class methods? First of all forget to use C linkage and then remove `extern "C"`. Now you have to `DllImport` the *raw* method name using `EntryPoint` parameter but you also have to change calling convention (because default is `StdCall` but classes use `ThisCall`), if you *forget* this then simply you're *running a bomb*. An example (just for information, I would really **avoid this** if you can access class API and you can add *plain* C exported function):

```
[DllImport("SomeDll.dll",
    EntryPoint="?CreateClass@Drive@UnmanagedDLL@@QAEPAV12@XZ",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
public static extern IntPtr CreateClass(IntPtr thisPointer);
```

Used like this:

```
IntPtr drive = CreateClass(IntPtr.Zero);
```

Now you can use `drive` for calls to other methods (you have right calling convention to do so, on X86 this is passed via `ECX`, not in the stack as it would do with `StdCall`, on X64 that's a completely different story but using attributes it'll work on both).

**EDIT**

How it may be done with C++/CLI? It should be easier and painless (implementation is just a skeleton).

Header:

```
public ref class Drive sealed
{
public:
    ~Drive();

    // Assuming you want to keep a static factory method
    static Drive^ CreateClass();

    property bool State
    {
        bool get();
        void set(bool value);
    }

private:
    Drive();

    DriveNativeImpl* _drive;
};
```

Implementation:

```
Drive::Drive()
{
    _drive = new DriveNativeImpl();
}

Drive::~Drive()
{
    delete _drive;
}

Drive^ Drive::CreateClass()
{
    return gcnew Drive();
}

bool Drive::State::get()
{
    assert(_drive != null);

    return _drive->GetState();
}

void Drive::State::set(bool value)
{
    assert(_drive != null);

    _drive->SetState(value);
}
```

In C# you'll see a *normal* managed class:

```
Drive drive = Drive.CreateClass();
drive.State = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After the edit, it has become much clearer to me. :) +1

I've been struggling for some days now trying to use a class a native DLL class in C#....Tried with C++/CLI wrappers at first, but even after looking at several articles for 3 days, I couldn't get it working and that's why I went to try PInvoke instead.

Comment: @Duane C++/CLI should be faster, especially if you're working with a native C++ class you may simply wrap it in a managed ref class that will forward each method call (translating parameters).

Comment: I could see from previous Stackoverflow articles that C++/CLI was recommended in most cases, which is why I tried it first. It did seemingly seem easier too.

Comment: Awesome! I will take a look. :)